# .NET Trace log viewer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, windows, logging

I have enabled trace logging in .NET to output the network data going back and forth so I can see the SOAP requests being sent to a web service. This seems to be the best way on a site that I can't debug or add a proxy between itself and the web service.

Here are the lines I've added to the web.config to enable it:

```
 <system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true"/>
  <sources>
   <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="1024">
    <listeners>
     <add name="TraceFile"/>
    </listeners>
   </source>
   <source name="System.Net.Sockets" maxdatasize="1024">
    <listeners>
     <add name="TraceFile"/>
    </listeners>
   </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
   <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="images/trace.log"/>
  </sharedListeners>
  <switches>
   <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
   <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
  </switches>
 </system.diagnostics>
```

Does anyone know of a log viewer for this? My searching has come up fruitless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change listener to XmlWriterTraceListener you can use [SvcTraceViewer.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to open the trace file. It is supposed to be used with WCF tracing and message logging but it works with any valid traces from XmlWriterTraceListener.

Comment: I will have a try and see how it goes.

Comment: You don't have to change listener, you can just add another listener within  `<sharedListeners>` tag

Answer (score 0):

IF your TextWriterTraceListener is writing to a text file, you can use a tail viewer (ie your view of the text file looks at the bottom of the file, constantly updating, rather than the start) like [baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/)

Comment: There is a lot of output, and all I really want is the soap messages going back and forth. 

tail will just show me the end of the file, which is not really an acceptable solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you want just soap messages you should write soap extension which will log them. Such soap extension is provided in MSDN as example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx